# cx_Oracle not connecting to database - possible TNSNAMES.ora issue

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am working on moving my code to a separate computer but I am having difficulty with cx_Oracle.

The issue arises when connecting to an alias which is located in my TNSNAMES.ora. I believe this is located in the correct file which the Oracle SQL developer is successfully connecting to, but every time I run
`con = cx_Oracle.connect(user = user, password = password, dsn = dsn)` python I get the 'ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified' error.

Is there any way to determine which file cx_Oracle is pointing to? Does it have to be setup? Could it be a 64 bit issue?

Comment: Did you try `tnsping` from command line?

Comment: How you tell your python prog where the tnsnames;ora is? via TNS_ADMIN? which version of cx_Oracle are you using? Can you upgrade to the newer version (oracledb)?

Comment: step 1: get the newer driver, so much easier/better than cx_Oracle, step 2, read the docs https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#optnetfiles

Comment: I just tried tnsping and everything appears ok and provides the exact dsn. When I manually copy this dsn into the function it appears to work fine. Not the solution I want but I will try the new driver

Comment: If you can't upgrade to the latest cx_Oracle (now called python-oracledb as gsalem and thatjeffsmith indicated), then add a call like `cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(config_dir="/etc/my-oracle-config-dir")` which points to the directory that contains your tnsnames.ora file.